# How to fix div height and cut down extra text from it

Tags: html, jquery, css

I am using bootstrap cards to display my content. I want every bootstrap card height to be equal. Everything else is fine but issue comes when I display discription as it is of variable length.
Sometimes it occupies two lines and sometimes three.
I want to fix description div height and cut down extra text from it.

**Note** Card are being displayed through loop

This is what I tried:

```
        $('address').height(30);
        var txt= $('address').text();    
        if(txt.length > 155) 
        $('address ').text(txt.substring(0,50) + '.....');
```

This is working perfectly fine for one card. But when there are multiple cards running in loop, same description text appears along every card due to this line: `var txt= $('address').text();`
How to make it work separately for each card?

Answer (score 0):

Your current select is targetting all the address element. You need to filter out the elements based on if condition. You can use jquery filter function for this.

Then iterate over those objects and modify the text.

```
var $addressToChange= $('address').filter(function(){
     return $(this).text().length > 155;
});    
$addressToChange.each(function(){
     $(this).text($(this).text()..substring(0,50) + '.....')
})
```

Comment: Brother I do know of ````$(this)```` selector. When I'll place this jquery script at bottom of page then how it'll get ````$(this)```` selector? How should I initiate this script so that it applies on each card separately?

Comment: `this` selector is used inside filter function and each function. You need to ensure copying all the above lines if you want to put it in the end.

Comment: I am pasting all lines down the page and nothing happening. Can you please be little more specify?

Comment: You need to include the jquery library.

Answer (score 0):

I am thankful to @Milind Anantwar for his answer as his answer gave me a clue. I little modify his answer and achieved my desired result by using this piece of code:

```
        $('address').height(40);
        $('address').each(function(i){
          if ($(this).text().length > 40)
          { 
            $(this).text($(this).text().substring(0,50) + '.....')
          }
        });
```